# rspec runtime per step

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, continuous-integration, rspec-rails

Is it possible to have rspec output the runtime for each step of a scenario? i.e.

```
Given I successfully authenticate
  > 50ms
And I create a valid request
  > 10ms
```

Taking this a step further, would it be possible to log and output the runtime of each layer (client/server) of a step? i.e.

```
 Given I successfully authenticate
  > Client: 10ms
  > Server: 40ms
```

Comment: is the end goal to actually benchmark your tests or your app?

Comment: two-birds...#1 identify step bottlenecks for ci optimization. #2 help identify performance issues during development. Not to take the place of proper monitoring and logging, but to highlight any potential red flags early.